# Update fieldPermissions with metadata api of Salesforce

Tags: soap, salesforce, soapui, savon, sfdc-metadata-api

I try to update the permissions on a field created from the API so that it is visible and usable.

so I do this via the salesforce metadata API.

```
responses = client.call(:update_metadata, message_tag: :updateMetadata, message: {metadata: { fullName: 'Admin', fieldPermissions: {field: "Contact.custom_attribute1_soap__c", editable: true, readable: true}}, :attributes! => {metadata: {"xsi:type" => "Profile"}}})
```

`client` is an instance of the gem Savon.

which gives me this, and seems correct to me !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header>
      <tns:SessionHeader>
         <tns:sessionId>s3ss10n1d</tns:sessionId>
      </tns:SessionHeader>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <tns:updateMetadata>
         <tns:metadata xsi:type="Profile">
            <tns:fullName>Admin</tns:fullName>
            <tns:fieldPermissions>
               <tns:field>Contact.custom_attribute1_soap__c</tns:field>
               <tns:editable>true</tns:editable>
               <tns:readable>true</tns:readable>
            </tns:fieldPermissions>
         </tns:metadata>
      </tns:updateMetadata>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

however, salesforce sends me back a mistake. 
After hours of searching the documentation I don't understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unable to determine type mapping for type Profile.  Type is illegal here.</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

One of you could explain my mistake to me, or give me a method to modify the permissions on a custom field created via the API, please?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the attribute `"xmlns": "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"`

Try:

```
responses = client.call(
     :update_metadata,
     message_tag: :updateMetadata,
     message: {
          metadata: {fullName: 'Admin', fieldPermissions: {field: "Contact.custom_attribute1_soap__c", editable: true, readable: true}},
          :attributes! => {metadata: {"xsi:type" => "Profile", "xmlns": "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"}}
```

}
    )

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following schema worked:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <tns:SessionHeader>
            <tns:sessionId>your_id</tns:sessionId>
        </tns:SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <tns:updateMetadata>
            <tns:metadata xsi:type="tns:Profile">
              <tns:fullName>Admin</tns:fullName>
                <tns:fieldPermissions>
                <tns:field>CustomObject__c.CustomField__c</tns:field>
                <tns:editable>true</tns:editable>
                <tns:readable>true</tns:readable>
                </tns:fieldPermissions>
            </tns:metadata>
        </tns:updateMetadata>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```